# Custom sort by key in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: sorting, key, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I need to create a custom key sort for my dictionary like this:

"Three",
"Cyan",
"Red",
"Car",
.....

When I using writeToFile the keys are sorted in alphabetically order. So if anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great. Thank you in advance.

Comment: First of all, `writeToFile` is deprecated in iOS 2.0–11.0. And even if you use it, it writes a property list, which is not sorted. And a dictionary is also not sorted but its stored values are accessed by the keys. So why and what do you want to sort?

Comment: I want to write a property list in osx. I need to put key "T" first and next "C", "R", "B" .........

Comment: `writeToFile` is deprecated in macOS 10.14. A dictionary on macOS is not alphabetically sorted and it's not possible to sort a dictionary. Why do you want a sorted property list? When you read the dictionary it won't be sorted.

Comment: A system require to read first key "T", "C", "R" ..... When i use xcode plist editor and I write "T" or drag at the first position and save, it keeps the position.

Comment: How does the system read the property list? Can't you use an array or custom class instead of a dictionary?

Comment: No that system read a dictionary

Comment: The system's dictionary is not sorted. What's the use of sorting the keys in the plist?

Comment: Why can we sort reorder by drag n drop in a plist editor?

Comment: Arrays can be sorted. And I think plists can be sorted so they can be compared.